# if a Bitcoin mining nounce is just 32 bits long how come is it increasingly difficult to find the winning hash?

Tags: algorithm, hash, bitcoin, sha256

I'm learning about mining and the first thing that surprised me is that the nounce part of the algorithm which is supposed to be randomly looped until you get a number smaller than the target hash .. is just 32 bits long.
Can you explain why then is it so difficult to loop an unsigned int and how come is it increasingly difficult over time? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is: try different nonce values in your potential block until you reach a block having a hash value below some given threshold.

I can't find the source right now, but I'm quite sure that since the introduction of special mining ASICs the 32-bit nonce is no longer enough to keep the miners busy for the planned 10 minutes interval between blocks. They are able to compute 4 billion block hashes in less than 10 minutes.

Increasing the difficulty didn't help anymore, as that reached the point where none of the 4 billion possible nonce values gave a hash below the threshold.

So they found some additional fields in the block that are now used as nonce-extension. The principle is still the same: try different values until you reach a block with a hash below the threshold, only now it's more than 32 bits that can be varied, allowing for the threshold to be lowered beyond the former 32-bit-implied barrier.

Comment: Very interesting, can you point me to some literature about the new fields added as nonce-extension? Thanks.

Comment: I'm nearly sure I read it in "Mastering Bitcoin" (1st ed.), that's been my main source for Bitcoin. But I don't have the book here right now...

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/what-is-the-extranonce. Looks like different implementations chose different solutions, sometimes even manipulating fields like timestamp.

Comment: @Pol O'Reilly has the whole book [online](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html) for free; here's the relevant excerpt from ch.8: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch08.html#extra_nonce. Originally miners used the timestamp to extend the nonce, but ASIC's became so powerful (req. even more increase in difficulty), that changing the timestamp enough would end up _invalidating_ the block; so after that miners started using extra space in the transaction script

Comment: p.s. save for offline viewing with `wget -r -nc -p -k -np -H -D chimera.labs.oreilly.com,amazonaws.com http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/index.html` (tested on mac)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not just the 32bit nonce that is involved in the calculation. The 1MB of transaction data is also part of the mining input. There is then a non-trivial amount of arithmetic to arrive at the output, which then can be compared with the target.

Bitcoin mining **is** looping over all 4billion uints until you find a "right" one.

The way that difficulty is increased, is that only some of the bits of the output matter. E.g. early on the lowest 11 bits had to be some specific pattern, the remaining 21bits could be anything. In theory there would be 2million "right" values for each transaction block, uniformly distributed across the range of a uint. Then the "difficulty" is increased so that 13 bits have to be some pattern, so now there are 4x fewer "right" answers, so it takes (on average) 4x longer to find one.

Comment: I still am not 100% clear, I get now that there is a 1MB of data to hash. It still means 4 billion entries to loop and calculate, am I to assume that the right answers diminish everytime and that's all which makes the calculations harder? Less right answers? Not more entries to loop?

Comment: @Pol Yes, fewer right answers. At the extreme, you could imagine a difficulty of 1 bit required, and ~50% of all nonces satisfy, or all 32 bits of output are needed, and there is only ~1 nonce that satisfies

Comment: @Ralf was pointing out that there are more fields other than the nounce to make the calculations harder. I was about to award your answer but he may have updated information. In the end I'm after creating some code to mine, for educational purposes, so I need it to work with the latest.